# MongoDB Realm - Filter Queries

Tags: mongodb, realm

In the scheme section where I connect the realm to the MongoDB collections there is a tab to add a filter query to filter the results being synced. I added a filter but every time I query on the app to load the data I get all the documents instead of filtered documents.
How can I filter the data the app receives?

Collection Schema:

```
{
  "title": "Group",
  "required": [
    "_id",
    "cDate",
    "name",
    "info",
    "isPublic",
    "joinWithRequest",
    "partition"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "admins": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "objectId"
      }
    },
    "members": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "objectId"
      }
    },
    "photoItems": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "title": "Item",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "cDate": {
            "bsonType": "date"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "id",
          "cDate"
        ]
      }
    },
    "videoItems": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "title": "Item",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "cDate": {
            "bsonType": "date"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "id",
          "cDate"
        ]
      }
    },
    "cDate": {
      "bsonType": "date"
    },
    "partition": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "info": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "icon": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "isPublic": {
      "bsonType": "bool"
    },
    "joinWithRequest": {
      "bsonType": "bool"
    }
  }
}
```

Filter:
[image: filter]

Client Query:

```
let groups = realm.objects(Group.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "cDate")
```

Comment: You could have a number of things causing that; it could be incorrectly formed or not filtering on the correct property for example. Please include your server filter, your client query and also your Realm objects and the expected behavior. Update your question and we'll take a look. In the meantime take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Keep in mind that the filter limits the number of documents your query runs against, it doesn't actually do the query or limit the returned results.

Comment: @Jay I added the relevant information, thanks in advanced

Comment: I think you missed this **your client query**. Also, you may want to re-read the documentation as I am not sure this kind of filtering is really what your after; it does't do a filter for your app, it does a filter on the server so there are less objects for your client query to query against, therefore increasing performance. Are you trying to increase performance?

Comment: @Jay I am trying to reduce the group documents being synced to the client to only the logged in users groups (the one's he is a member of). Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking about is (was) called a query based sync. While it limited the amount of data sync'd it also was limited by the number of users, system resources etc.

> At this time query based sync is no longer supported in MongoDB Realm

However, you can get much of the same functionality by leveraging partitions - which are required for sync'ing anyway. Let me give a high level example.

Suppose you have a 'posts' app with users and then posts done by users of specific groups. For this example, this user belongs to Group_0 and Group_1. Your user object may look like this

```
class UserClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var _id: //a users uid
   @objc dynamic var user_name = ""
   let groupPartitionList = List<GroupClass>() //will populate with Group_0 and Group_1
}
```

and a post may look like this

```
class PostClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var _partitionKey: GroupPartition = ""

    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @obcj dynamic var post = ""
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "_id"
    }
}
```

Suppose there are 50 different groups.

Upon the user authenticating and the user object populating, you would then know the user belongs to Group_0 and Group_1 which could be displayed in a popup menu - defaulting to the first group, Group_0.

Once the user logs in, get just the Group_0 posts

```
let whichPartition = myUserObject.groupPartitionList[0] //object at index 0 = Group_0
let config = user.configuration(partitionValue: whichPartition)
Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config) { result in
   ...
   let group0Posts = realm.objects(PostClass.self) //loads just the posts Group_0
}
```

As you can see, there is no query: the data is limited by the partition key e.g this will not read posts from any other group - only posts with a partition key of Group_0

Likewise, if the user changes the popup to Group_1, only posts with partition key of Group_1 will sync and no other. So even though there are 50 groups and thousands of posts, you will only download and sync Group_0's and Group_1's via the partition value.

You can augment this further by using a server filter (as mentioned in the comments to the question) to withhold certain data so the amount of data being queried at the server level is smaller.

For example, you could add a filter to ignore any posts that are older than 5 years. That will significantly speed up queries by reducing the amount of data being queried (which effectively could reduce the number of results because those are ignored)

There's some excellent reading in the MongoDB Realm Docs [Partition Atlas Data Into Realms](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/partitioning/#partition-atlas-data-into-realms).